# sudo !! equivalent on Windows cmd

Tags: command-line, terminal, cmd.exe, sudo, command-line-arguments

I'm looking for a **cmd.exe** equivalent to Linux's `sudo !!` and other bang-commands such as `!x`, `!?x`, `!!:p` and `!!*` mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15137462/7026554).

Comment: I don't think so, `cmd` is an ancient beast with a lot of unfixable problems due to backward compatibility. You don't even have an equivalent to `sudo` in Windows. Powershell is much more powerful and you can do the above things with `Get-History`

Comment: You can try `cygwin` if you really miss Linux commands.

Comment: @Cricrazy cygwin is great, but my use case exclusively involves `cmd`.

Comment: The just released [gsudo v0.7.1](https://superuser.com/a/1527054/45898) suports `!!` on CMD. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `gsudo`, **a sudo for windows** that allows either to run commands with elevated permissions **on the current console**, to elevate the current shell, or launch elevated commands on a new console.

Examples

```
gsudo {command} [arguments]
gsudo md "C:\Program Files\MyApp"

# spawn the current shell (Cmd/PowerShell/PSCore) in a new console window
gsudo -n

# spawn PowerShell in a new console window
gsudo -n powershell
```

**UPDATE**:
Since `gsudo v0.7.1`, it supports the Unix-sudo Bang Bang syntax, on CMD:

- `gsudo !!` elevates the last executed command.
- `gsudo !prefix` elevates the last executed command that starts with prefix.
- `gsudo !?infix` elevates the last executed command that contains infix.

**Installation**

- Install with Scoop: `scoop install gsudo`
- Install with Chocolatey: `choco install gsudo`

Manuall installation methods, docs & source at https://github.com/gerardog/gsudo

Comment: Brilliant!  Especially fun as I used winget to install it for that extra-pseudo 'nux feel. :)

Answer (score 0):

The sudo equivalent is the [runas command](https://ss64.com/nt/runas.html),
used to execute a program under a different user account.

Example of use :

```
runas /user:an-administator-account "cmd.exe /C mycommand"
```

Windows is different than Linux in that by default even an admin account
doesn't run with elevation, although, unlike a non-admin account,
it can elevate itself.

For methods of self-elevation see:

- [Is there a command which can elevate the Command Prompt in place?](https://superuser.com/questions/1200239/is-there-a-command-which-can-elevate-the-command-prompt-in-place/1200271)
- [5 Ways to Trigger UAC Elevation from Command Line](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/trigger-uac-elevation-from-command-line-with-elevate-utility/)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't works in Windows 10. It will run as that user but without elevation/admin rights.

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli: You are right that a Linux user will expect this, although Windows is different. I added links to some some self-elevation methods.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the other half of the question, you can use **doskey** to view or parse the command history. Doskey is installed and active by default on all supported versions of Windows.

This shows your command history:

```
doskey /history
```

You could parse and push the results to runas, but wrapping it in a batch file would make it a lot simpler at the prompt.